# iOS Rendering Email half the size

Tags: html, ios, email, html-email, responsive-emails

**Issue**

I tested my email in Litmus and it renders at half the size of the email window only in iOS mobile phones as shown [**here**](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6865-ios11-makes-strange-not-100-width-in-native-mail-app). It sounds like Apple made this update in iOS 10 so users would have the ability to zoom into their email. **I need help getting the responsive email rendering to the full width on iOS phones.**

**Troubleshooting**

When I remove all of my css styles, it renders properly (full width) on the phone. But I need the email to be responsive.

**Online solutions that are not working for me**

1. I have seen this question online in a couple of places like [**here**](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6871-ios-11-rendering-my-email-1-2-the-width-of-the-screen) and [**here**](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6865-ios11-makes-strange-not-100-width-in-native-mail-app) with the solution being as simple as adding this meta tag inside the  `<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />`.
2. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" shrink-to-fit="no">`
3. body { width: 100%; max-width: 600px; }
4. `<body style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;>`
5. Setting the table widths to 100% with max-width: 600px;

**Here is my Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" shrink-to-fit="no"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 

    <meta class="mktoColor" id="headlineColor" mktoname="Headline Color" default="#003a70"> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="textColor" mktoname="Main Text Color" default="#333333"> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="mkto-callout-text-bg-color" mktoname="Callout BG Color" default="#00843d"> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="mkto-callout-text-color" mktoname="Callout Text Color" default="#ffffff"> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="mkto-cta-text-link" mktoname="CTA Text Link Color" default="#00843d"> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="mkto-cta-button-bg-color" mktoname="CTA BTN Bg Color" default="#003a70"> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="mkto-footer-link-color" mktoname="Footer Link Color" default="#418fde"> 
    <title>Test</title> 

    <style type="text/css">

  html, body {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      height: 100% !important;
      min-width: 100% !important;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
  }
  * {
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  .ExternalClass {
      width: 100%;
  }
  div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
      margin: 0 !important;
  }
  table, td {
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
  }
  table {
      border-spacing: 0 !important;
      border-collapse: collapse !important;
      table-layout: fixed !important;
      margin: 0 auto !important;
  }
  table table table {
      table-layout: auto;
  }
  img {
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }
  .yshortcuts a {
      border-bottom: none !important;
  }
  a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
      color: inherit !important;
  }
  </style> 
    <style type="text/css">
  .button-td, .button-a {
      transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  }

  /* Media Queries */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .email-container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .fluid, .fluid-centered {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
    }
    .fluid-centered {
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
    }
    .stack-column, .stack-column-center {
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        direction: ltr !important;
    }
    .stack-column-center {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    .center-on-narrow {
        text-align: center !important;
        display: block !important;
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
        float: none !important;
    }
    table.center-on-narrow {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
  }
  </style> 
  </head> 
  <body bgcolor="#f2f2f2" width="100%" style="margin: 0; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" yahoo="yahoo"> 
    <table bgcolor="#f2f2f2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
      <tbody> 
        <tr> 
          <td> 
            <center style="width: 100%;"> 
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container mktoContainer" id="mkto-container" style="width: 600px;">
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="logo-container" mktoname="Header logo"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center"> 
                    <div class="mktoImg" id="header-logo-image" mktoname="Header Logo Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                      <a href=""><img src="" width="250" height="50" style=""></a>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="body-copy-section" mktoname="Body copy with headline"> 
                  <td style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"> 
                    <div class="mktoText" id="headlineText" mktoname="Headline">
                      <p style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 32px; color: ${headlineColor};"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing&nbsp;elit </p>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="mktoText" id="Paragraph1text" mktoname="Paragraph Text">
                      <p style="text-align: left; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor};"> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent laoreet malesuada cursus. <a href="" style="color: ${mkto-cta-text-link};" target="_blank"><u>This is a&nbsp;link, it is underlined and the hex code is #eb6b19.</u></a> </p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="hero-container" mktoname="Hero Image"> 
                  <td class="full-width-image"> 
                    <div class="mktoImg" id="hero-banner-image" mktoname="Hero Banner Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                      <a href=""><img src="" width="600" alt="alt_text" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;"></a>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="centered-btn" mktoname="CTA Button"> 
                  <td> 
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; text-align: center;" class="button-td">
                            <a href="" style="background: ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; border: 15px solid ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a" id="mkto-button" mktoName="Button"> 
                            CTA BUTTON 1
                            </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="video-screenshot" mktoname="video screenshot"> 
                  <td class="full-width-image"> 
                    <div class="mktoImg" id="full-width-image" mktoname="Full Width Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                      <a href=""><img src="" width="600" alt="Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;"></a>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="bullet-group" mktoname="Bulleted List"> 
                  <td style="padding-right: 40px; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"> 
                    <div class="mktoText" id="Paragraph2text" mktoname="Paragraph Text">
                      <p style="text-align: left; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor};">Maecenas sed ante pellentesque:</p>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="mktoText" id="bulletedList" mktoname="Bulleted List">
                      <ul> 
                        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin text-overflow: ellipsis; word-wrap: break-word; color: ${textColor}; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </li> 
                        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-overflow: ellipsis; word-wrap: break-word; color: ${textColor}; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li> 
                        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-overflow: ellipsis; word-wrap: break-word; color: ${textColor}; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li> 
                      </ul>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="signature" mktoname="Signature"> 
                  <td style="padding-right: 40px; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"> 
                    <div class="mktoText" id="Paragraph3text" mktoname="Paragraph Text">
                      <p style="text-align: left; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor};"> Regards, <br> <br> <strong><span style="color: #003a70">Our Team</span></strong><br></p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="three-col-img-text" mktoname="Three columns with image and text"> 
                  <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;"> 
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"> 
                                    <div class="mktoImg" id="lower-left-image" mktoname="Lower Left Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                                      <a href=""><img src="" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" class="fluid"></a>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor}; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> 
                                    <div class="mktoText" id="lowerLeftImageText" mktoname="Lower Left Image Text">
                                      Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                          <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"> 
                                    <div class="mktoImg" id="lower-middle-image" mktoname="Lower Middle Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                                      <a href=""><img src="http://na-ab25.marketo.com/rs/433-TWV-220/images/Image-Placeholder-170x170.png" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" class="fluid"></a>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor}; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> 
                                    <div class="mktoText" id="lowerMiddleImageText" mktoname="Lower Middle Image Text">
                                      Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                          <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"> 
                                    <div class="mktoImg" id="lower-right-image" mktoname="Lower Right Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                                      <a href=""><img src="http://na-ab25.marketo.com/rs/433-TWV-220/images/Image-Placeholder-170x170.png" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" class="fluid"></a>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor}; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> 
                                    <div class="mktoText" id="lowerRightImageText" mktoname="Lower Right Image Text">
                                      Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="callout-box" mktoname="Callout Box"> 
                  <td bgcolor="${mkto-callout-text-bg-color}" valign="middle" style="text-align: center; background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;"> 
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px;"> 
                            <div class="mktoText" id="calloutText" mktoname="Callout Box Text">
                              <p style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${mkto-callout-text-color};;"> <strong>Call out box:</strong> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent laoreet malesuada cursus. Maecenas scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut&nbsp;erat. </p>
                            </div> </td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> 
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="two-col-img-text" mktoname="Two columns with image and text"> 
                  <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;"> 
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"> 
                                    <div class="mktoImg" id="top-left-image" mktoname="Top Left Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                                      <a href=""><img src="http://na-ab25.marketo.com/rs/433-TWV-220/images/Image-Placeholder-270x270.png" width="270" height="270" alt="alt_text" class="fluid"></a>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor}; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> 
                                    <div class="mktoText" id="topLeftImageText" mktoname="Top Left Image Text">
                                      <p>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                          <td class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center"> 
                                    <div class="mktoImg" id="top-right-image" mktoname="Top Right Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                                      <a href=""><img src="http://na-ab25.marketo.com/rs/433-TWV-220/images/Image-Placeholder-270x270.png" width="270" height="270" alt="alt_text" class="fluid"></a>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td style="font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor}; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> 
                                    <div class="mktoText" id="topRightImageText" mktoname="Top Right Image Text">
                                      <p>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="left-img-right-copy" mktoname="Left image, right copy"> 
                  <td dir="ltr" align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding: 10px;"> 
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px;"> 
                                    <div class="mktoImg" id="bottom-left-image" mktoname="Bottom Left Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                                      <a href=""><img src="http://na-ab25.marketo.com/rs/433-TWV-220/images/Image-Placeholder-170x170.png" width="170" alt="alt_text" class="center-on-narrow"></a>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                          <td width="66.66%" class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor}; padding: 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> 
                                    <div class="mktoText" id="bottomImageText1" mktoname="Bottom Image Text 1">
                                      <strong style="color:${textColor};">Class aptent taciti sociosqu</strong> 
                                      <br> 
                                      <br> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
                                      <br> 
                                      <br> 
                                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:left;"> 
                                        <tbody> 
                                          <tr> 
                                            <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="" style="background: ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; border: 15px solid ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> 
                                                CTA BUTTON 2 
                                                </a> </td> 
                                          </tr> 
                                        </tbody> 
                                      </table>
                                    </div> 
                                    </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="right-img-left-copy" mktoname="Right image, left copy"> 
                  <td dir="rtl" align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding: 10px;"> 
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px;"> 
                                    <div class="mktoImg" id="bottom-right-image" mktoname="Bottom Right Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                                      <a href=""><img src="http://na-ab25.marketo.com/rs/433-TWV-220/images/Image-Placeholder-170x170.png" width="170" alt="alt_text" class="center-on-narrow"></a>
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                          <td width="66.66%" class="stack-column-center"> 
                            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr> 
                                  <td dir="ltr" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px; color: ${textColor}; padding: 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow"> 
                                    <div class="mktoText" id="bottomImageText2" mktoname="Bottom Image Text 2">
                                      <strong style="color:${textColor};">Class aptent taciti sociosqu</strong> 
                                      <br> 
                                      <br> Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
                                      <br> 
                                      <br> 
                                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:left;"> 
                                        <tbody> 
                                          <tr> 
                                            <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; text-align: center;" class="button-td"> <a href="" style="background: ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; border: 15px solid ${mkto-cta-button-bg-color}; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> CTA BUTTON 3</a> </td> 
                                          </tr> 
                                        </tbody> 
                                      </table> 
                                    </div> </td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> </td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="thick-divider" mktoname="CC, Phone and Web link"> 
                  <td class="full-width-image"> 
                    <div class="mktoImg" id="footer-image" mktoname="Footer Image" mktolockimgsize="true">
                      <a href=""><img src="" width="600" alt="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;"></a>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
              </table> 
            </center> </td> 
        </tr> 
      </tbody> 
    </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: replacing your meta tag with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` and see what it does.

Comment: That's the first time I have tried that on this project! It did not work however.

Comment: Just tested on litmus and all iOS 10 devices display it properly? https://litmus.com/checklist/emails/public/0172964

Comment: @Syfer It is displaying properly in your test... That tells me maybe that it could be the Marketo classes that are added. That's one thing I didn't mention is that the email is through Marketo and I had to test on Litmus by sending a sample email from Marketo to Litmus to get the full Marketo render.

Comment: I did see it was from Marketo. Update your code with the final code as its sent thru Marketo please? As it is your HTML's perfect it seems.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out! The code above is directly what I put into Marketo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164792/discussion-between-syfer-and-spz1).

Comment: I had to head out to make an appointment, but I can work on this again tomorrow. Thank you so much for all your help! I looked at your profile and it looks like you are the right person who knows a lot about emails.

Comment: @Syfer helped me solve this issue. In my style class, "table", once I removed the table-layout: fixed !important; it worked perfectly. Thanks, @Syfer!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as I found out on chat, the issue was table fixed CSS that was causing the issue. Once you removed it, the tables start going full width.

Before:

```
table { 
            border-spacing: 0 !important; 
            border-collapse: collapse !important; 
            table-layout: fixed !important; 
            margin: 0 auto !important; 
          }
```

After:

```
table { 
            border-spacing: 0 !important; 
            border-collapse: collapse !important; 
            margin: 0 auto !important; 
          }
```

Cheers